# Selectively retrieve data from tables when one record in first table is linked to multiple records in second table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables:

```
1.  Tbl_Master: columns:
     a. SEQ_id
     b. M_Email_id
     c. M_location_id
     d. Del_flag

2.  Tbl_User: columns
     a. U_email_id
     b. Last_logged_date
     c. User_id
```

First table Is master table it has unique rows i.e. single record of all users in the system.
Each User can be uniquely identified by the email_id in each table.

One user can have multiple profile, which means for one us_email_id field in the tblUser table, there can be many user_id in tbl_User,
i.e there can be multiple entries in second table for each user.

Now I have to select only those users who have logged in for last time before, lets say '2012', i.e before 1-Jan-2012.

But if one user has 2 or more user_id and one user_id has last_logged_date less than 2012
But other user_id has greater than 2012 then such user should be ignored.

In the last all all the result user will be marked for deletion by setting DEL_flag in master table to ‘Yes’
For eg:

```
    Record in Tbl_Master:
    A123 ram@abc.com D234 No
    A123 john@abc.com D256 No

    Record in tbl_User can be Like:
    ram@abc.com  '11-Dec-2011'   Ram1
    ram@abc.com  '05-Apr-2014'   Ram2
    john@abc.com '15-Dec-2010'  John1
```

In such case only John's Record should be selected not of Ram whose one profile has last_logged_date>1-Jan-2012

Comment: Thanks for editing, i posted this in rush thats why poor editing!

Comment: Can you post some sample data..

Comment: @G One: done chk it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility was

```
SELECT
    m.M_Email_id,
    MAX(u.Last_logged_date) AS last_login
FROM
    Tbl_Master m
INNER JOIN
    Tbl_User u on u.U_email_id = m.M_Email_id
GROUP BY m.M_Email_id
HAVING
    -- Year(MAX(u.Last_logged_date)) < 2012   -- use the appropriate function of your DBMS
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(MAX(u.Last_logged_date))) < 2012 -- should be the version for oracle
 -- see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions045.htm#i1017161
```

Your `UPDATE` operation can use this select in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks ill try this!
will let you know once check it out

Comment: Tried this: i got error in last Line:
ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier

Comment: GOt it Changed: 
        Year(MAX(u.Last_logged_date)) < 2012
        to 
        (MAX(u.Last_logged_date)) < '01-Jan-2012'

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this ans is in sql server, I haven't worked on Oracle.

```
select * from Tbl_Master 
outer apply
(
    select U_email_id,max(Last_logged_date)as LLogged,count(U_email_id) as RecCount 
    from Tbl_User 
    where Tbl_User.U_email_id = Tbl_Master.M_Email_id
     group by U_email_id

)as a
where RecCount >2
and Year(LLogged) < '2012'
```

Try this **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9b9c/1)**

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I m workig on SQL Developer, let me check if it works fine in it.

Comment: which DBMS you are using? Oracle/MS SQL/MYSQL?

Comment: Please let me know, if it works. Deleting same user is easy task write delete srcipt & in Where clause write M_Email_id in(...My Ans....[with select M_Email_d from])

Comment: We have Oracle 11g on the Server. there is actually no need to delete the user. We can just set their Del_flag column to Yes

Comment: well i can chk that after some time!
i'll surely let you know once i check it

Comment: Tried your code, Having error at Outer Apply: 
         ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Your query seems to correct,
but not working fine in Oracle,
But let work it out!